# Metro App Change ListView Selected Item Content Foreground

Tags: xaml, listview, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` and modified it's `DataTemplate` with 2 `TextBlocks`.

The first `TextBlock` contains a **Heading**, the second a **Sub-Heading**.

I style the 2 `TextBlocks` with different colours.

Here's an example of the `ListViewItem` in **Normal** view.

[image: Normal]

Here's an example of the `ListViewItem` in **Selected** view.

[image: Selected]

So my question is how do I change the `Foreground` colours of the `TextBlocks` in **Selected** views? Hoping to do this in the xaml. I've tried setting different brushes, which work for items that haven't explicitly been styled.

Not sure how to handle this scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metro App ListView SelectedItem Selected VisualState](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010582/metro-app-listview-selecteditem-selected-visualstate)

Comment: **RESOLVED**:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010582/metro-app-listview-selecteditem-selected-visualstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some researching and thinking out of the box, found a suitable solution that works:

[Metro App ListView SelectedItem Selected VisualState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010582/metro-app-listview-selecteditem-selected-visualstate)

I can see this being handy for a couple of other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use visual states.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock x:Name="txtOne" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Green"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtTwo" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray"/>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtOne" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtTwo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to play with the visual state.

In your ResourceDictionary, set a value for these brushes "ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush", "ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush", "ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush". It will override the default brushes of your application.

Example:

```
    <!-- Overrides default ListBox brushes -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource GreenColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightGreenColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
```

Here is a usefull link when developping in WinRt, which references the brushes name, for the default controls of winRt.

[WinRt default brushes names and values](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes)

Comment: This solution won't work, c0D3l0g1c wants to change the foreground of textblocks in the datatemplate.