# Metro App ListView SelectedItem Selected VisualState

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

I have a **Metro App** with a `ListView` that contains this definition:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lv" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" IsTabStop="True" SelectionMode="Extended" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tb1" Foreground="{StaticResource SecondaryColourBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" x:Name="tb2" Foreground="{StaticResource SecondaryColourBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tb3" Foreground="{StaticResource QuadColourBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tb4" Foreground="{StaticResource QuadColourBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

When the `ListView` has an item selected, I want to change the `Foreground` of `tb1` and `tb2` **ONLY** to `White`. How do I go about doing this?

I tried overriding **Themed Brushes** and `VisualStateGroup` `SelectionStates` for `Selected`, which hasn't helped. A working code example would be appreciated.

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977737/metro-app-change-listview-selected-item-content-foreground/15978702#15978702) you already, didn't it work ?

Comment: Nope... thought it did, but didn't. Even created a dummy project, in case my scenario was too complex - but still didn't work.

Comment: Check these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551766/xaml-listview-change-image-source-for-selected-item & https://gist.github.com/brendankowitz/5619131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally **RESOLVED** this, thanks to this article for giving me the idea:

http://blog.davemdavis.net/2012/11/12/controlling-the-datatemplate/

**Created a `BooleanToColourConverter`**

```
public sealed class BooleanToColourConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? AppResources.TertiaryColourBrush : AppResources.PrimaryColourBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is SolidColorBrush && ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color == AppResources.TertiaryColourBrush.Color;
    }
}
```

**Added this in App.xaml**

```
<common:BooleanToColourConverter x:Key="BooleanToColourConverter"/>
```

**Then used it like this:**

```
Foreground="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColourConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
```