# Change template of list item in WinRT app based on selection state

Tags: windows, xaml, winrt-xaml

I try to change the display of a ListViewItem in a WinRT app based on whether the item is selected. In WPF, I would have used a style trigger, but this is not available in WinRT. So after searching the web for some time, I think I must use the visual state manager. As I understand, the ListView has a visual state group "SelectionStates" which holds the states I am interested in. So I came up with the following ItemContainerStyle that I apply on my ListView:

```
        <Style x:Key="itemContainerStyle" TargetType="SelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="SelectorItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Collapsed" />

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The normal items show up as expected (so I assume that my style is applied), but the selection stuff does not work at all. Why? I assume that the states are triggered automatically, isn't it? So how do I fix it?

Note: I use "SelectorItem" as target type because I want to use the same style on a grid view, too. Is that a problem? Changing it to "ListViewItem" did not solve my problem though...

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: The `SelectionMode` of the list was set to `None`. Hence, the state change was never triggered.

Furthermore, there are multiple selection states like `SelectedUnfocused` which must be considered. I found that doing a web search on " styles and templates" is very helpful for finding the appropriate page on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `(UIElement.Visibility)` as value of `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`'s `Value` property.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have changed that, but I has no effect at all... I shomehow feel that the state change is not triggered at all, but I have no idea how to debug that.

Comment: ok check this, I think visual states are not working properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010582/metro-app-listview-selecteditem-selected-visualstate/17123613#17123613

Comment: Thanks for your help - I found the problem in the meantime: selection was disabled on the list.

Comment: Hay @Christoph, I have the same prob, if the Selection is disabled in the List, so can I use the SelectionStates in VisualState Manager in ListviewItem Styles. As the FocusStates work fine but I need the SelectionStates because When we Lost the Focus then the Animation in VisualState is Reversed, how to overwhelmed this plz.